# call a method in the parent activity after dialog fragment is dismissed

Tags: java, android

I have a activity which prompts a dialog fragment. I want to call a method in the parent activity when the dialog fragment is dismissed. Here is the activity that contains the dialog fragment.

```
public class HomScr extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.das_boa);

        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize(){

        tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ProEdiCon dia_fra = new ProEdiCon();
                dia_fra.show((this).getSupportFragmentManager(), "pro_edi_con");
            }
        }
    }


    private void method_to_run_onDismiss(){
        tv.setText("method to run is executed");
        Toast.makeText(this, "method to run successfully executed on dismiss Dialog Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And the below code is the DialogFragment which gets dismissed in certain point and after that the parent activity must call the method to run on dismiss.

```
public class ProEdiCon extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bun) {
        View pro_vie = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pro_edi_dat, container, false);

        TextView tv = pro_vie.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText("I am the Dialog Fragment who is gonna be dismissed soon");

        Button btn = pro_vie.findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        }

        return pro_vie;
    }
}
```

So can anybody help me do this?

Comment: If the method in your activity is public, then you could try to call `((HomeScr) getActivity()).method_to_run_onDismiss();` , also you might want to check if `getActivity() instanceof HomeScr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create interface like this

CallBackListener.java

```
public interface CallBackListener {
     void onDismiss();
}
```

Then in your fragment

```
public class ProEdiCon extends DialogFragment {

private CallBackListener callBackListener;
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    //getActivity() is fully created in onActivityCreated and instanceOf differentiate it between different Activities
    if (getActivity() instanceof CallBackListener)
        callBackListener = (CallBackListener) getActivity();
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bun) {
    View pro_vie = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pro_edi_dat, container, false);

    TextView tv = pro_vie.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setText("I am the Dialog Fragment who is gonna be dismissed soon");

    Button btn = pro_vie.findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(callBackListener != null)
                callBackListener.onDismiss();
            dismiss();
        }
    }

    return pro_vie;
}
}
```

And finally in your Activity

```
public class HomScr extends AppCompatActivity implements CallBackListener {
    TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.das_boa);

    initialize();
}

private void initialize(){

    tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
    Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ProEdiCon dia_fra = new ProEdiCon();
            dia_fra.show((this).getSupportFragmentManager(), "pro_edi_con");
        }
    }
}


private void method_to_run_onDismiss(){
    tv.setText("method to run is executed");
    Toast.makeText(this, "method to run successfully executed on dismiss Dialog Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onDismiss() {
    method_to_run_onDismiss();
}

}
```

Comment: Why should we write a lot of code if we can achieve it an easy way using *DialogInterface*

Comment: @HarishKamboj DialogFragment dont have setOnDismissListener

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Dialog` and set Dismiss listener and listen for the event when dialog will be dismissed

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ProEdiCon dia_fra = new ProEdiCon();
                dia_fra.show();
                dia_fra.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                        //do some action here
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

and your Dialog will  be like this:

```
public class ProEdiCon extends Dialog {

    public ProEdiCon (@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pro_edi_dat);

        TextView tv = pro_vie.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText("I am the Dialog Fragment who is gonna be dismissed soon");

        Button btn = pro_vie.findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: and where should I put it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a `DialogListener` interface inside your Dialog class and call it before the dialog is dissmissed.

Interface with your method

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void method_to_run_onDismiss();
}
```

Dialog - create an instance of the interface and call it right before `dismiss();`

```
public class ProEdiCon extends DialogFragment {

private MyInterface myInterface;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bun) {
       ...
        myInterface = (MyInterface) context;
        Button btn = pro_vie.findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            myInterface.method_to_run_onDismiss();
                dismiss();
            }
        }

        return pro_vie;
    }
}
```

Activity class implement the interface and use the method you already have

```
Public class HomScr extends AppCompatActivity implements MyInterface {
TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.das_boa);

        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize(){

        tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ProEdiCon dia_fra = new ProEdiCon();
                dia_fra.show((this).getSupportFragmentManager(), "pro_edi_con");
            }
        }
    }


    private void method_to_run_onDismiss(){
        tv.setText("method to run is executed");
        Toast.makeText(this, "method to run successfully executed on dismiss Dialog Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```